# Appending new key to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to add elements to a dictionary in the following way:

```
a = {}
a['b'] = 1
a['a'] = 2
```

Finally a looks like:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 1}
```

But actually I wanted the dictionary to contain keys in the order:

```
{'b': 1, 'a': 2}
```

Can anyone explain me this? Why are the keys getting sorted alphabetically when actually dictionaries (hashmaps) don't have any order?

Comment: You should use `OrderedDict`

Comment: They're not being sorted, that just happens to be how it's being shown. It's arbitrary.

Comment: When I iterate through the dictionary, first 'a' gets printed and then 'b'. Can you explain me this?

Comment: Everyone has already explained it to you. Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: Depends of the hash function used, and the implementation of a dictionary. With a different one, it could very well be 'b' then 'a'

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that dictionaries are not ordered, but hashed. As a result, the order of a dictionary should not be relied on.

You can use the OrderedDict to help you achieve your goal:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a = OrderedDict()
a['b'] = 1
a['a'] = 2

 > a
 > OrderedDict([('b', 1), ('a', 2)])
```